# How do I read startup items from registry on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry, 64-bit

I am currently trying to get a list of all autoruns, but I am struggling on a 64-bit system. When I use:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", False)
```

It shows me entries from:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", False)
```

Anyone know why and/or how to fix this?

I should also state that the items in HKLM\..\Run are different to those in HKLM\..\Wow6432Node..\Run.

Comment: Why on earth are people voting this as off topic and suggesting migration to superuser?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your process is a 32 bit process and so, on a 64 bit OS, the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) comes into play. The `HKLM\Software` key is redirected and there are two views of it, a 32 bit view that your process is finding, and a 64 bit view.

It is true that if you run a 64 bit process, you will see the 64 bit view of the registry. However, that is not the full story. Windows processes `CurrentVersion\Run` entries from both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry. So, if you just switched to an x64 or AnyCPU process you would then be missing the autoruns stored in the 32 bit registry view.

So, since your goal is to list all the autoruns, you will need to read both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry. You can do that using the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration that was introduced in .net 4. This allows a 32 bit process to access the 64 bit view of the registry. And indeed it allows a 64 bit process to access the 32 bit view of the registry.

If you want a process that runs on both 32 bit and 64 bit systems you will need to target either x86 or AnyCPU. And then use `RegistryView` to read both views of the registry if you detect that you are running on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

That's happen because your application is compiled for x86 platform and running on a 64bit operating system. There is a comprensive article on [Registry Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by
>   providing separate logical views of certain portions of the registry
>   on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit and 64-bit
>   registry calls to their respective logical registry views and maps
>   them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection
>   process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit
>   application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit
>   Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit
>   Windows

You could fix the problem compiling your application for AnyCPU platform

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would never have guessed this was the case!